# how to display specific fields from db using the selected value in dropdown listbox in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

```
   <select id="qualification" class="form-control"> 
     <option selected="selected">SELECT</option> 
     <option value="pick"</option>
     <?php $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT qualification From
     enquire"); 
      $row = mysqli_num_rows($sql); 
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
     { echo "<option value='". $row['qualification'] ."'>".$row['qualification']."</option>" ; } ?>
    </select>
```

how to retrieve fields in table format from database using qualification ?

Comment: You are asking for SQL?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: ......................

Comment: Qualification is a column name. But if it contains column name you want to use for a next query i dont know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
       <?php 
        $sql="SELECT Option1, option2 FROM yourTable";
        $result = mysqli_query($YourDBconnection,$sql);
      ?>
```

**your SELECT like**

```
<select>
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo'<option>'.$row['option1'].'<option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: click here to learn about  `https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-function.mysql-fetch-assoc.html`

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
<select id="qualification" class="form-control"> 
     <option selected="selected">SELECT</option> 
     <option value="pick"</option>
     <?php $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT qualification From
     enquire"); 
      //$row = mysqli_num_rows($sql); 
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)))
     { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['qualification']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['qualification']; ?> </option> 
<?php } ?>
    </select>
```

You may wanna reconsider your codes and use prepared statement to avoid SQL injection.
The below code is prepared statement

```
<select id="qualification" class="form-control"> 
     <option selected="selected">SELECT</option> 
     <option value="pick"</option>
     <?php $sql =$con->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT qualification From
     enquire");
      $sql->execute(); 
      $result = $sql->get_result(); 
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
     { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['qualification']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['qualification']; ?> </option> 
<?php } ?>
    </select>
```